# WebRTC TURN Server - I set it up, but it's not working

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I've set up a text chat service using the PeerJS implementation of WebRTC's data channel. PeerJS provides a basic signalling server for this purpose, but I have tried to replace that with STUN and TURN servers set up through XirSys (recommended by SimpleWebRTC, another WebRTC library). I haven't deployed to the web yet.

Using Node to serve my static files locally, it will work on a local network (when I am sitting next to the person and they navigate to my ip/port in the browser), but will not work when connecting through different access points on the same network (i.e. at work, on opposite ends of the building).

My hypothesis is that it's hitting a firewall, but still directing traffic to PeerJS' signalling server without falling back to the XirSys STUN and TURN servers I've tried to set up. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
var stun = {};
var turn1 = {};
var turn2 = {}; 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://api.xirsys.com/getIceServers",
    data: {
        ident: "myusername",
        secret: "long-alphanumeric-secret-key",
        domain: "www.adomain.com",
        application: "anapp",
        room: "aroom",
        secure: 1
    },
    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        stun = data.d.iceServers[0];
        turn1 = data.d.iceServers[1];
        turn2 = data.d.iceServers[2];
    },
    async: false
});

var conn;
  // Connect to PeerJS, have server assign an ID instead of providing one
  var peerID = prompt('What would you like your screen name to be?');
  var peer = new Peer(
    peerID, 
    {key: 'mypeerjsserverkey', debug: true}, 
    {
    config: {'iceServers': [
        {url: stun.url},
        {url: turn1.url, credential: turn1.credential, username: turn1.username},
        {url: turn2.url, credential: turn2.credential, username: turn2.username}
      ]
    }
  });
```

NOTE: My ident, secret, domain, etc. obviously aren't accurately represented here. I don't think that's where my problem is.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you getting ICE candidates from your ICE servers? Are you sure your credentials are correct?

Comment: If your setup is correct, then mostly yes, you're hiting a firewall. On the same network the local ICE candidates can be resolved and traffic can go through, but to go everywhere in your company's network firewall rules regarding UDP/TURN/STUN should be set

Comment: Should you place the 'config' object inside the same object as key/debug etc? The constructor only takes two arguments for `new Peer()`

Answer (score 2):

If you email us a wireshark capture of your STUN/TURN traffic, we should be able to outline where your problem is.  Messages sent over signalling are separate but parallel to WebRTC messages.  Therefore, if the app is working but the messages are being sent over signalling, then it's possible the configuration of the application isn't correct.

XirSys provides TURN via UDP over TCP through port 80/443, so if the signalling is connecting and flowing, so should the TURN.

Also, looking at your code, if you pass data.d from your getIceServers success handler to the PeerJS config, that should reduce your code quite a bit :-)  The ICE string you're reconstructing doesn't need to be broken down.

Regards,
Lee
XirSys CTO

Comment: Thank you for answering (and apparently creating an account for that purpose), Lee! What email address should I use to reach out to you? I'll try and grab a wireshark capture within the next couple of days and send that over. I'll be honest - I've only been coding for a couple months, so I've most likely configured something incorrectly. I'd certainly appreciate any help I can get, though.

Comment: No worries. You can reach us here: experts@xirsys.com [=